# Entire Print Shifted

Tags: troubleshooting, elegoo-neptune-3

Can anyone tell me what would cause an entire print to be shifted about 8mm?
I have a new Elegoo Neptune 3 Pro (which is doing an awesome job so far!).
I started printing this [Treasure Chest Puzzle Box](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5414034) overnight, and this morning it looked pretty good until I noticed that after approximately 3 layers, the print shifted by about 8mm. I think it shifted again by about 1mm after 1 layer. The rest of the print is perfect.
Unfortunately, I pulled the print off and closed my Cura file before I took note of which direction the print was on the bed, so I don't know which dimension was shifted - the direction the bed slides or the direction the extruder head moves.
I printed on the normal Cura profile.
Thanks.
[image: print shifted]

Answer (score 1):

One of the following might be the case:

- Your X or Y belt may be loose. Are the belts under enough tension?
- The speed / acceleration / deceleration of your head may be so high that the belt slips. Can you try to move the bed or the head and see if the belt slips?
- The head of the extruder might have got caught in an extruded part that somehow got lifted up or fell over. Can you see any sign of a part that got bumped by the extruder head?
- Your cat might have gotten a little too interested and whacked the printer's bed with its paw.

Answer (score 1):

### Classic layer shift

The whole print shifted. This means that for some reason, the bed moved more than the printer thought it did. This is typically happening in the following situations:

- The bed was prevented from moving, usually due to the cable snagging somewhere
- The bed moved too much, usually due to being hit
- The bed moved when not told to, usually due to the operator bumping into it.
- The Printhead did anything that resulted in the bed moving, but on the printhead.
- The belt was loose and skipped a few steps.